# Drop Down menu not aligning correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

Apologies if this has been asked and answered before. I have a drop down menu which works flawlessly in chrome and Firefox but in IE the drop down boxes are positioned to the right of where I am hovering and i can't get it to be underneath. If someone could explain how to fix this I would be grateful.

Website of example is: 
https://www.imac-repairs.co.uk/test/menu.html

**CSS**

```
 body {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    background-image:url("image/a.jpeg");
    }

#icon {
    height:15px;
    width:15px; 
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

nav { 
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

nav ul {
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    }

nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    }

nav a {

    padding:5px 25px;   
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover{
    background:gray;
}

nav ul li ul li a{
    color:black;
    font-size:17px;
}

nav ul li ul a:hover {
    background: gray;       
}

nav a:hover { 
    background-color: gray;   
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    font-size:17px;
    background:white;
    opacity:0.9;
    border-radius:3px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
    width:140px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top:-60px;
    left:170px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Responsive dropdown menu
</title>
<link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
        <nav>
         <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Menu 2</label>
                    <a href="#">Menu 2 <img src="image/icon.png" id="icon" /></a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Menu 2.4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.5</a></li>

                    </ul> 

                </li>
                <!-- End of First Tier Drop Down -->
                <li>                
                <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Menu 3</label>
                <a href="#">Menu 3 <img src="image/icon.png" id="icon" /></a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 3.4</a></li>                   

                </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- End of Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <li>

                <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Menu 4</label>
                <a href="#">Menu 4 <img src="image/icon.png" id="icon" /></a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 4.6</a></li>

                </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- End of third Tier Drop Down -->
                <li>
                <!-- Fourth Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Menu 5</label>
                <a href="#">Menu 5 <img src="image/icon.png" id="icon" /></a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 5.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 5.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 5.3</a></li>          

                </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- End of fourth Tier Drop Down -->
                <li>
                <!-- Fifth Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Menu 6</label>
                <a href="#">Menu 6 <img src="image/icon.png" id="icon" /></a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu 6.6</a></li>

                </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- End of Fifth Tier Drop Down -->
                <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the `li`s, and `left: 0` to the child `ul`s:

```
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    }

nav a {

    padding:5px 25px;   
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover{
    background:gray;
}

nav ul li ul li a{
    color:black;
    font-size:17px;
}

nav ul li ul a:hover {
    background: gray;       
}

nav a:hover { 
    background-color: gray;   
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    font-size:17px;
    background:white;
    opacity:0.9;
    left: 0;
    border-radius:3px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
    width:140px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top:-60px;
    left:170px; 
}
```

It doesn't look exactly the same, as you can see:

**IE:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
[image]

But it mostly works right.

Comment: @RickKap This is a hack and not a solution to the problem which will continue throughout your continued progress if you have any. You are in "quirks mode".

Comment: what are you going on about, man!!! I had a problem and out of the goodness of there heart TricksfortheWeb found the solution.

Comment: "The goodness of my heart" thanks man! But he's right, it's just a hack, and there are still going to be problems that will crop up, just try to fix those.

Comment: Well it seems to work fine on the website, so thanks again. BTW if I wanted to display the menu in the middle instead of the left is this something easy to do?

Comment: Sure, just use transforms.

Comment: Maybe when I mentioned middle I should have meant center of the screen instead of on the left. doesn't transform rotate things?

Comment: Transform can do a lot more than just rotate, but I assume you want the entire thing to be in the middle, which you can get using `text-align` on the `ul`.

Comment: thanks, I tried adding text-align: center; to ul but it didn't shift it to center

Comment: Which `ul` did you put it on?